# Remove newlines generated by Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember JS.  I have a template using a component to render links.  However, when the links are rendered, there are new lines created that throws off the page.  I've tried the examples that I've found (ie - using swung dash) but nothing has worked.  Here is the main template for each statement, using the entity-link component:

```
{{#each model as |entity|}}
<li class="entity-list-item list-group-item">
  <span class="entity-primaryValue">{{entity-link entity=entity}}</span>
  <span class="entity-type">({{entity.type}})</span>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

And here is the template of the component (called entity-link):

```
{{#if isPerson}}
  {{link-to entity.primaryValue "people.show.basic-info" entity.id}}
{{else}}
  {{link-to entity.primaryValue "entities.show" entity.type entity.id}}
{{/if}}
```

And here is the computed value of isPerson in the entity-link component.js file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isPerson: Ember.computed.equal('entity.type', 'person')
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but none of the examples I've tried have removed the new lines that are inserted.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? I'm guessing that you are getting DIVs wrapped around each LI?

Comment: Yes - lots of divs, but including one around the entity.primaryValue.  That div is not necessary.

Comment: According to what I was reading, adding a '~' to the component reference should have removed new lines (ie - {{~ entity-link entity=entity ~}}.  But that has not worked.

Comment: emberjs bin to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your component to specify the tag name:

/components/**.js

```
...
tagName: 'li',
classNames: ['entity-list-item', 'list-group-item'],
...
```

And remove the `li` from your template.

Comment: No luck - it moves the entity.type value to a separate row when displayed.  I changed the component to:

Comment: oops - sorry:
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Component.extend({
      isPerson: Ember.computed.equal('entity.type', 'person'),
      tagName: li',
      classNames: ['entity-list-item', 'list-group-item']
});

Comment: Got it - used tagName: '' in the component, and that removes the unneeded div tags.  Thanks for all your help.